# Node.js Trade Notification for Steambot

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm not a coder, but I'm asking on behalf of my web developer who isn't fluent with english, for everyone's expertise.

I'm trying to achieve a real time trade notification on my website.

I have the node.js bot working for all trading purpose already and its interacting with the web with socket.io. Inventory is working. But I do want to add an addtional functionality when the trade offer is send, a notification will also in real time event sent to user on my website at the same time my bot sent a trade offer to the user in steam.

Below is a screenshot example,

https://gyazo.com/ec41e836605f2284f834dd7606693e22

Really appreciate if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Nobody will be able to answer this well without sample code of whatever he's attempted so far.  Otherwise, he might as well just go research on socket.io tutorials and whatnot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all depends on the way you handle your data.

If you are making it so the bot sends a trade offer to the user then when you call your trade offer add in a

```
socket.emit('tradeOfferSent', {

});
```

to that user which can be picked up on the client side by

```
socket.on('tradeOfferSent',function(data) {

});
```

conversely if you are making your users send trade offers to the bot you can use on `'newOffer'` from steam-tradeoffer-manager to emit the data as above.

Inside the `on.socket('',function(){});` you are able to add anything you want as an notification. Such as using sweetalerts.

Comment: Thanks matt for your input, how do i +rep

Comment: Should be an up arrow somewhere close to the top of the question along with accept this answer

Comment: I need at least +15 rep points to +rep u haha. but in any case i have open a seperate question on inventory stuff which is not capturing on my mysql database.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951669/inventory-issue-with-node-js-steambot

Comment: Just accept the answer then that will give rep. You don't need rep to accept

Comment: Hey matt could I add you on skype to discuss some matters with you

Comment: @nodebotquestion sure send me a message

Comment: @nodebotquestion skype: matt.barber94