# Inventory issue with node.js steambot

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, steam-web-api

I have tried to deposit 56 items using node steam, and on accepting Trade it returns only 29 Items as new items.

I am using getReceivedItems() to get the Items with update assetid.
Here is the link, https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-tradeoffer-manager/wiki/TradeOffer#getreceiveditemsgetactions-callback

On accepting Trade, i have manageed "sentOfferChanged" event and with in that i have called getReceivedItems og TradeOffer objct to get updated information of Items in Trade as Below:

tradeOffer.getReceivedItems(function(err,items){

})

Is there any problem I could fixed?

Comment: Hi again. Please can you post more code. A lot of websites I know limit trade offers to 10 items. Not sure if this is due to a limitation with the system or just a limitation to their website. Will find out upon inspecting your code :)

Comment: Hi Matt, the scenario is based on socket communicated with user, user deposited 20 inventory, bot received, then we use ajax to update the web inventory, but for some reason it only update 10 items out of 20, or randomly 13 items out of 20. the link is the code. https://gyazo.com/05a9763628cc816f99af26e1275d5819 and https://gyazo.com/e1152f476ad6f1b1ca92b1926d301faf